# use of endiannes specific types __be32/__be16/__le32/__le16 in the kernel

Tags: c, types, linux-kernel, endianness

Linux kernel has the types `__be32`, `__be16` etc. defined in the kernel' `include/uapi/linux/types.h`.

However they're simply typedefs to `__u32`, '__u16' and such. Also, in case `sparse` is used for C code analysis, they add `gcc` specific flag `__bitwise`.

As far as I understand __be* or __le* types can be used for endian dependent variables. But they serve more as annotation facility, just to indicate that we're working with a big-endian or little-endian object. Is that correct assumption?

Comment: They are for annotation and for static analysis by the [Sparse](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/dev-tools/sparse.html) checker.

Comment: Has Linux ever been ported to a Big Endian computer?

Comment: @Lundin Of course it has. https://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Linux for m68k, mips, arm at least are big endian. The last two are also little endian, endianness is selected in the devices firmware on power-on there.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Along with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/linux/downloads/oracle-linux-sparc-3665558.html

Comment: Yes, the idea is to produce warnings when you try to mix types in your code.